# xml error in webaplication publishing and running

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-applications

i have developed a asp.net web application in visual studio 2008.

its running perfectly when i build it in visual studio.

but when i published it and configured in iis and try to browse that its geeting an xml error

i tried to browse this

http://localhost/myproject/Pop3Client.aspx

eror is like this

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://localhost/myproject/Pop3Client.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
-^

i dont what is the problem.

its working right when i build in visual studio...

but when i do this through iis its not..

can anyone help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the FrontPage-related (VTI) folder on the server and see if that fixes it? The VS publish operation uses this folder but you can still deploy without it by copying. Are you using CSS Adapters? If so, then they do not play nice with the VTI stuff.